# Reason for relaxing limit in derivative in this context?

Tags: math, optimization, gradient-descent, derivative

Consider the following paragraph from [NUMERICAL COMPUTATION](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html) of the deep learning book..

> Suppose we have a function $y = f(x)$, where both $x$ and $y$ are real
> numbers. The derivative of this function is denoted as $f'(x)$ or as
> $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. The derivative $f'(x)$ gives the slope of $f(x)$ at
> the point $x$. In other words, it speciﬁes how to scale a small change
> in the input to obtain the corresponding change in the output:
> $f(x+\epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x)$.

I have doubt in the equation $f(x+\epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x)$ given in the paragraph.

> In strict sense, the derivative function $f'$ of a real valued
> function $f$ is defined as
>
> $$f'(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
>  \dfrac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$
>
> wherever the limit exists.

If I replace the original definition of the derivative as follows

$$f'(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$

then I can obtain the equation given in the paragraph i.e,  $f(x+\epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x)$.

But, my doubt is that how can I modify the definition with $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}$ to an approximation with out limit? How can the following two are same?

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon} \text { and } f'(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation
$$f(x + \epsilon) \approx f(x) + \epsilon f'(x)$$
is justified from taylor series. It is not derived from the limit definition of a derivative. Let $f'(a)$ and $f''(a)$ exist for $a$ in the interval $(x, x+\epsilon)$. Then,
\begin{align*} 
f(x + \epsilon) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}f''(b)
\end{align*}
where $b$ is some number between $(x, x + \epsilon)$. If $\epsilon << 1$, then $\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}f''(b)$ is small so it can be ignored, leading to the approximation.

[taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)

Answer (score 1):

It is just an assumption. If we assume $\epsilon$ is small enough (depending on the function $f$), you can remove the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$ for the approximation.